# Query Not working as expected

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

So I wrote a rather - unattractive function -  a while ago and I was re-factoring some code and I realized my query function doesn't work ... I recently made a post about how [my tansient posts were not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115240/transient-pagination-not-working-properly/115331?noredirect=1#115331) and it all boiled down to the basics of the query not working.

Now yes, I do actually get a post object back, and yes I do manage to loop through it and display some content. How ever the paging isn't working, its the same set of posts regardless of page number your on.

So in reading that post I checked to make sure I am getting the max number of pages. and I am.

But as stated, no matter the page I am on the posts are the same. Does the same concepts applied in the answer to my other question apply here or ...

```
    protected function _query_post($query, $remove_nav = false){
        global $wp_query;
        $original = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($query);

        if($wp_query->have_posts()){
            while($wp_query->have_posts()){
                $wp_query->the_post();

                if(isset($this->_options['post_before'])){
                    echo $this->_options['post_before'];
                }

                $this->_components->thumbnail($this->_options);

                $this->_components->title($this->_options);

                the_excerpt();

                if(isset($this->_options['post_after'])){
                    echo $this->_options['post_after'];
                }               
            }
            if($remove_nav != true){
                $this->_general_loop_nav($wp_query->max_num_pages);
            }
        }else{
            $this->_components->error_page($this->_options);
        }

        $wp_query = $original;  
    }
```

Keep in mind this function is planning to be re-factored.

This question has **not already been answered** as the query coming in looks like this:

```
'query' => array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => get_query_var('page') // Look i'm already paged
),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination not working with custom loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't preserving the `paged` query var in your query. You can accomplish this by making line 4:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query($query . "&paged=" . $original->query_vars['paged']);
```

UPDATE: After the edit on the OP, the issue was that the paging variable, `paged` was in the query being sent to the function. But, there was a typo so that the page variable (which would have been false in this case) was actually being sent to the function.

Therefore, we corrected:

```
'query' => array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'paged' => get_query_var('page')
),
```

to

```
'query' => array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
),
```

Comment: So that kind of worked. The issue is now it sias no posts were found, the query coming in is just `'posts'`

Comment: Also see updated OP - the query coming in is already paged.

Comment: the `page` query var would give a page id (or probably `false` in this case). You need to get the `paged` query var.

Comment: please see the updated OP I have already gotten that.

Comment: unless it's a typo, you have `'paged' => get_query_var('page')` where it should read `'paged' => get_query_var('paged')`